# Are there any regulations on how VFR Aircraft have to dodge if they are facing each other?

Tags: regulations, visual-flight-rules, see-and-avoid

I thought about what happens when there are two Aircraft flying VFR, facing each other. VFR Aircraft are not guided by ATC, they have to seperate from other traffic on their own.

I thought it could be quite dangerous if both pilots try to make way and both are flying the same maneuvers.

- Is there any regulation on how VFR Aircraft have to fly, to seperate from the other aircraft? Something like: Both should fly to the left or something like that.

Or is this not relevant because this rarely happens and even if, there is enough time to seperate.

I am not asking for any specific country. Tell me what you know.

Comment: You asked a question without any country specified, then selected an answer valid only for the US. Fortunately this question is redirected to another post where things are clearer, but you may still improve consistency by adding a tag "FAA" or "USA" (let's imagine Chinese users start to do the same, things will be quite difficult to follow).

Comment: Just to educate myself more on StackExchange: Why have I received (so many) down-votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [14 CFR 91.113](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.113):

> **(e)Approaching head-on.** When aircraft are approaching each other head-on, or nearly so, each pilot of each aircraft shall alter course to the right.

[Here is a good read from AOPA](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2008/november/flight-training-magazine/who-has-the-right-of-way) about who has the right of way in a number of different situations, all covered by 91.113.

Comment: What if you're inverted?

Comment: @Steve Not sure why you would be, but I guess you'd have to go left.

Comment: Would that be violating the regulation? (just kidding, of course!)

Comment: Not sure if it would be violating *that* regulation, but if you are performing aerobatics close enough to other traffic that they would have to avoid you, you'd probably be violating *some* regulation, like careless/reckless operations.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is: both turn (to their own) right.

---

But the more important rule it the *half circle flight level* rule.

This says that:

- when heading between 000 and 179 degree you fly at an "odd" flight level (IFR, VFR +500ft) like 3500ft, 5500ft, 7500ft,..
- when heading 180 to 359 you fly at an "even" flight level (IFR, VFR +500ft) like 4500ft, 6500ft, 8500tf.

This way planes in opposite direction have 1000ft difference in height.

Comment: The even/odd altitude rule only applies over 3000 feet AGL (not MSL).

Comment: Also, IFR is 1000's, VFR is 500's. So VFR altitudes are 3500, 4500, 5500, etc. IFR altitudes are 3000, 4000, 5000, etc. See [91.179(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.179) for IFR and [91.159](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.159) for VFR.